# Solspace Calendar Pagination

Tags: pagination, solspace, calendar, solspace-calendar, events

I have a list of Solspace Calendar events that I would like to paginate. According to the documentation, the pagination parameter and variable pair should work the same as channel:entries. I am able to limit the events to 10 with the limit="" parameter, but the {paginate} variable pair does not display the pagination links.

```
{exp:calendar:events calendar_name="Events" limit="10" date_range_start="" orderby="event_start_date" sort="ascending"}
            <div>
                <h4><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
                <h5>{event_start_date format="%j %F %Y :: %g:%i%a"}&ndash;{event_end_date format="%g:%i%a"} 
                <p>{event_location}</p>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <hr />
            {paginate}Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages &nbsp; {pagination_links}{/paginate} 
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Comment: To eliminate the obvious set the limit really low, say to "2" -- that way you can be certain it's not an issue of not having enough results to paginate. Does pagination output still not show after trying that?

Comment: @AlexKendrick I've adjusted the limit to 2 but still no pagination output.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `limit="10"`, try using `event_limit="10"`. From the {exp:calendar:events} documentation:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#event_limit

Comment: I replaced the limit parameter with event_limit. Still no pagination...

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 10 events on "today"? If you keep date_range_start="" empty or don't use it, Calendar defaults to "today". Same for date_range_end="". Make sure you have more events to display than the value in the limit="" parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the date range parameter and updated to the latest calendar version. Pagination is working!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the [paginate](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#paginate) parameter on your opening `calendar:events` tag. Try adding `paginate="bottom"` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: That is obviously an error in my code and I was almost certain that this would fix the problem, but I just added the parameter and there's still no pagination.